# Automatically change the scanner save folder to the current open folder

Tags: windows

I am looking for guidance on how to configure my scanner in a way that it can automatically save all the scanned documents to the folder that is currently open on my computer. Can you please suggest the steps I need to follow to set up this feature?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To clarify, I have a large number of documents that need to be scanned and saved in separate folders. I am looking for a way to configure my scanner and computer so that when I open a folder and scan a document, it is automatically saved in that same folder.

Comment: Are you scanning from inside the scanner's application, or is the scan initiated from the scanner? What models are the scanner and your computer? What is your operating system? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your reply. I'm using a Windows 11 PC, and a Brother ADS-2200 scanner, with the iPrint&Scan software.

Comment: I don't know iPring&Scan, but if it's doing the scan then the answer must lie in its settings/options. Go through all the settings supported by it and try to find such option.

Comment: @John When replying to request for clarification always [edit] the question to add that information. And regarding your question nothing to add to the previous comment. If possible there will be a setting in the software itself.